# Ljung-Box statistic / AR-GARCH weak predictions

Tags: time-series, econometrics, garch

How would you interpret the Ljung-Box statistics in the following AR-GARCH output? What is the difference between the $R^2$ and $R$  Ljung-Box statistics? Does the GARCH model seem to be effective, based on these figures? I ran the model on simple returns. I couldn't find any explanation of how to interpret them.

```
Mean and Variance Equation:
data ~ arma(3, 0) + garch(1, 1)
<environment: 0x00000000112f0798>
[data = hubtimeseries]

Conditional Distribution:
norm 

Coefficient(s):
     mu          ar1          ar2          ar3        omega       alpha1        beta1  
-1.5250e-05   2.4290e-02  -9.4327e-02  -2.6432e-02   2.1657e-05   1.2717e-01   8.7299e-01  

Std. Errors:
based on Hessian 

Error Analysis:
         Estimate  Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
mu     -1.525e-05   4.694e-04   -0.032    0.974    
ar1     2.429e-02   1.656e-02    1.467    0.142    
ar2    -9.433e-02   1.664e-02   -5.670 1.43e-08 ***
ar3    -2.643e-02   1.645e-02   -1.607    0.108    
omega   2.166e-05   4.622e-06    4.686 2.79e-06 ***
alpha1  1.272e-01   9.663e-03   13.160  < 2e-16 ***
beta1   8.730e-01   8.760e-03   99.651  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Log Likelihood:
 8157.293    normalized:  1.891327 

Standardised Residuals Tests:
                               Statistic p-Value   
Jarque-Bera Test   R    Chi^2  15056.37  0         
Shapiro-Wilk Test  R    W      0.9644693 0         
Ljung-Box Test     R    Q(10)  21.16408  0.01997802
Ljung-Box Test     R    Q(15)  25.52058  0.04337416
Ljung-Box Test     R    Q(20)  30.94273  0.05595107
Ljung-Box Test     R^2  Q(10)  6.461079  0.7751532 
Ljung-Box Test     R^2  Q(15)  7.471077  0.9432367 
Ljung-Box Test     R^2  Q(20)  10.20694  0.9642624 
LM Arch Test       R    TR^2   6.838069  0.8681264 

Information Criterion Statistics:
    AIC       BIC       SIC      HQIC 
-3.779408 -3.769070 -3.779413 -3.775758
```

Also, should ARMA-GARCH model normally predict security prices better than an ARMA model, all else held equal? Mine doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would you interpret the Ljung-Box statistics in the following AR-GARCH output?

The Ljung-Box statistics indicate quite significant autocorrelations in standardized residuals since p-values for `R` are all below 0.06. This result should be perceived as negative (in a well specified model you would expect the p-values to be high).

> What is the difference between the $R^2$ and $R$  Ljung-Box statistics?

My guess is that `R` stands for standardized residuals (residuals from the conditional mean model divided by the fitted standard deviations from the GARCH model), while `R^2` stands for squared standardized residuals.

> Does the GARCH model seem to be effective, based on these figures?

The low p-values of the Ljung-Box statistics for `R` indicate that the model is performing poorly. The high p-values of the Ljung-Box statistics for `R^2` and of the ARCH-LM test for `R` are encouraging. However, formally neither the Ljung-Box nor the ARCH-LM test is valid for standardized GARCH model residuals. These tests are suited for raw data, not for output from a model targeted to remove the conditional heteroskedasticty. Li-Mak test should be used instead.

> Also, should ARMA-GARCH model normally predict security prices better than an ARMA model, all else held equal?

I doubt any of the models would be successful due to the "no free lunch" argument. However, an ARMA-GARCH is more likely to correctly capture the features of financial returns than a pure ARMA model. Since conditional heteroskedasticity is characteristic to financial returns, neglecting it would mean a misspecified model. So even if neither model would predict well, you may still prefer the model that is more likely to be well specified, which is the ARMA-GARCH model.

Comment: Thank you! It's odd that R^2 and R paint two completely different pictures. For some reason, my ARMA-GARCH model doesn't appear to be any better at predicting prices than my ARMA model based on the mean absolute error they give. I'm using log returns as the data input for both models, is that the right way to do it? And if I can't find a statistical package that can implement the Li Mak test, what would you recommend as an alternative (to say "this model is appropriate and statistically significant")? Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Using log returns is fine. Li-Mak test is available in R, I have used it myself, just forgot what the package name was. Try looking for it harder. If you can't find Li-Mak test, perhaps you could use the Ljung-Box and the ARCH-LM tests as they are (misleadingly) included in the automatic output (as can be seen above). Not everyone knows that they are invalid when applied on GARCH model output, so maybe you will slip through. Also, I would not say it's odd that `R^2` and `R` diagnostics give different pictures. After all, conditional mean and conditional variance are different things.